# Inverse correlation between two scales

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have a range of numbers beginning at one, that increment by one to an upper limit which could be anywhere between 100 and 200.

I'm trying to create a function that will convert these numbers to the range 0.5 to 20, where **one always = 20, the max value always equals 0.5** and the remaining numbers are interpolated between the two.

Assuming the numbers one to max are in column A I've managed to convert the old scale to the new one with this:

```
=(((A1-1)*(20 - 0.5))/(MAX(A:A) - 1))+0.5
```

Which can be expressed as `(((OldVal - OldMin) * (NewMax - NewMin)) / (OldMax - OldMin)) + NewMin`

This correctly converts the scales magnitude

```
200 20
199 19.90201005
198 19.8040201
197 19.70603015
196 19.6080402
195 19.51005025
194 19.4120603
    etc...
8   1.185929648
7   1.087939698
6   0.989949749
5   0.891959799
4   0.793969849
3   0.695979899
2   0.59798995
1   0.5
```

What I need to do now is invert the scale, so that the max (100 to 200) = 0.5 and the min (1) = 20.

How can I do this, bearing in mind the max is dynamic and can be anywhere between 100 and 200? Is there perhaps another way to solve the original problem of creating an inverse correlation?

Ideally, if there is some clever mathematical trick (you prob. guesses I'm no math Boy!) I'd like to be able to fish out any number in the sequence without calculating the whole sequence first e.g `returnValue = someFunction(120)`, though this isn't essential.

Many thanks.

Comment: You could get this done easily using VBA if that's an option?

Comment: Yeah, I guess i could throw the values into a couple of arrays and reverse one of them but ideally I'm looking for a more mathematical solution. My gut tells me there must be some simple equation that would do it. Thanks for the idea as a fallback though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming linear interpolation, you can use `y = mx + b`, where `x` is your input (in this case, 1 to some unknown value between 100 and 200), `y` is your output (in this case, 20 to 0.5), and the slope (`m`) and the intercept (`b`) are determined dynamically as the upper limit of `x` changes.

I'll define the unknown value between 100 and 200 as `z`.

We have two equations and two unknowns. (Keep in mind `z` is known, it is just that it is dynamic). Here is the system of equations:

```
20 = m*1 + b
0.5 = m*z + b
```

Some linear algebra:

```
19.5 = m*(1-z)
m = 19.5/(1-z)
```

And:

```
20*z = m*z + b*z (the equation '20 = m*1 + b` multiplied by 'z')
0.5 = m*z + b
20*z - 0.5 = b*(z-1)
b = (20*z - 0.5)/(z-1)
```

So your equation to relate the two is:

```
y = 19.5*x/(1-z) + (20*z - 0.5)/(z-1)
```

Again where `z` is the number between 100 and 200.

Comment: @Absinthe Just 4th grade algebra :P Thanks haha

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse/invert the order of your data in column B, by entering the following formula on Column C:

`=INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)+1-ROW())`